# How to search a string in list in sql?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have been using sql for quite a time but unable to figure out below query logic.

I'm extracting two values

1. First_name i.e abc
2. FIRST_NAMES_LIST (list containing first names) i.e ['abc','abc','cba','dba'] (this may contain junk values also in between strings)

I trying to search first_name in first_name_list and return 1 or 0, using below logic

CASE FIRST_NAME in FIRST_NAMES_LIST then 1
else 0

but this isn't giving correct result

Can somebody please help.

Thanks,
Naseer

Answer (score 1):

Look this information:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php

INSTR is a function which return <> 0 if your parameter match. If not it return 0.

I no have any clear example in your ennunciate to give you the correct answer. See the functionalities.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would parse out your json into a table object ( I don't know how to do that in Oracle) and then search your table object where the object contains the value, but that is pretty expensive. It would be more robust and would be able to handle special characters/corner cases better.

On the other hand, if the names are going to stay simple (ie, no quote marks ' or commas), you could use a LIKE expression and search the string.

`CASE WHEN FIRST_NAMES_LIST LIKE '%''' + FIRST_NAME + '''%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 0):

Yes im currently using INSTR but query is taking bit of time. hope resolves this issue. thanks.

Comment: I can't answer you without code. You are using a CURSOR? Your table has many data? There are many questions I cannot know currently.